# I would like some tips for debugging WCF Web Service exceptions

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I've created a WCF service and when I browse to the endpoint I get the following fault:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode 
            xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">
            a:ActionNotSupported
      </faultcode> 
      <faultstring xml:lang="en-GB">
            The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver,
            due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. 
            This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched
            Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security
            mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender
            and receiver have the same contract and the same binding
            (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).
      </faultstring> 
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I've fixed the problem but didn't enjoy the experience! Does anyone have any tips or tools for debugging problems like this?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm struggling with the same problem.

Comment: Can you share with us What was the root cause for the above error? i am getting this while integrating with a 3rd party applications WCF service.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found [SvcTraceViewer.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) to be the most valuable tool when it comes to diagnosing WCF errors.